# How to hide edit plugin in inline or in-place Editor RTE of touch UI for particular Page?

Tags: dialog, touch, aem

We are using Richtext editor component in our site using in-place editing feature. Can someone please tell me how to hide edit bar or authoring featuring for a particular page for richtext in-place editing component. I am able to do this for dialog specific component but facing issue for in-place editing rich text .

Comment: in-place editing is component level feature configured at cq:Editconfig. You want this feature in most pages but want to be disabled in specific page only?

Answer (score 1):

There is a property named `active{Boolean}` which can be set on the `cq:inPlaceEditing` child node of the component's `cq:editConfig` node. Setting this property to `false` will disable the in-place editing of the richtext editor component.

However, note that this will disable the inline editing in all pages including this component.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the inline editing of any component in the "cq:editConfig" node you remove "cq:inplaceEditing" node.